# I want the same result for query as google gives on search for particular query

Tags: javascript, c#, web-services, google-places-api

I'm using Google Place API for getting the list of the places according to my query but I am not getting the same list as the google give. In fact, I am confused that whether I should us nearbysearch or textsearch in Google Place API.

As I have mentioned I am not getting the same result as Google maps give for the query. I have also supplied the location as well.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?location=22.258651999999998,71.1923805&query=cafe&key=API_KEY

This API calls give me a different result compare to Google search and given location is my current location from where I am searching in Google as well. So if I am passing my current location then I think the result of both should be the same but I am not getting it.

Answer (score 0):

Google Places API will not return the same results as a search using Google Maps. I am assuming that is what you mean by "searching in Google as well." We are not sure what the search algorithm is for Google Maps and they're not going to tell us.

Places API responses are determined by the type of request (find place, nearby, text) and the parameters you supply. I too have struggled to find the right combination to obtain results the same as Google Maps.

I did a search on Google Maps with the latitude/longitude you specified and for nearby cafes. I was able to get nearly the same list of cafes with this places request:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=22.258651999999998,71.1923805&keyword=cafe&rankby=distance&key=API_KEY`

The first 6 responses to this request listed the same businesses that Google Maps did and in the same order. The remaining responses were all **cafe** type businesses, same as listed by Google Maps but not in the same order. The Places response excluded the **restaurant** type businesses that appeared in the Google Maps listing, imo a better response.

Note that I used a **Nearby** search to obtain these results. It is more appropriate for your use case. A Textsearch according to the Places API documentation is most useful when making ambiguous address queries.